# Changes to /etc/sysconfig/keyboard without restart?

Tags: redhat, configuration

`cat /etc/sysconfig/keyboard`

KEYBOARDTYPE="pc"

KEYTABLE="uk"

#### Question:

- Do you have to restart for changes to effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to restart for `/etc/sysconfig` changes to take effect, unless you can run whatever script that reads them again (i.e., `/etc/init.d/networking` for /etc/network/).

That said, one of `/etc/init.d/{console-screen,keymap}.sh` might do what you want, but they look like stuff that's only run at boot time.

Comment: Rebooting made no difference when I tried this (`KEYTABLE`, `KEYBOARDTYPE`)